# Show that $2^{2^n}+5$ is divisible by $3$ for all $n \geq 1.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

This is part of a larger proof that I am trying to do, but this is a fact I'm trying to wrap my head around and prove. Based on a Sage program, I was able to deduce by pattern that $2^{2^n}+5$ is divisible by $3$ for all $n \geq 1.$ If you factor numbers of this form until $n=6$ on Sage, you get that a prime factor of all of them is $3.$ I tried proving this through induction, but I couldn't quite figure out how to make the argument for the inductive step. I know modular arithmetic is the way to go, but it isn't something we've studied yet in class! Thank you for your help.

Comment: $2^n$ is even when $n\geq1$. $2^{2k}\bmod3$ for any $k$ is $1$ since $2\equiv-1\bmod3$. Thus, $$2^{2^n}+5\equiv6\equiv0\bmod3$$

Comment: Since $n>0,$ $2^{2^n}=4^{2^{n-1}}\equiv 1\pmod 3.$

Comment: For induction, write $x_n=2^{2^n}+5$. Then $x_{n+1}=(x_n-5)^2+5$.

Comment: Without modular arithmetic: $\,2^{2^n}+5=\left(4^{2^{n-1}} - 1\right) + 6=(4-1)(\dots)+6\,$.

Comment: You might try proving $2^{2^n}-1$ is divisible by $3$, say by using induction. Adding six would obviously give you some slightly larger multiple of three.

Comment: @dxiv What is the identity that allows you to "expand" the exponential term into $(4-1)(...)$? I couldn't find it anywhere but I do know it.

Comment: @BoostMatch It's commonly known as the difference of powers identity $\,a^n-b ^n=(a-b)(\dots)\,$, see for example [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Sum_and_difference_of_powers#Differences_of_Powers). It is equivalent to the sum of a geometric progression formula $\,1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{n-1}=\left(x^{n}-1\right)/\left(x-1\right)\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you! So for this problem, would it look like $4^{2^{n-1}}-1=(4^2-1)(4^{2^{n-2}}+...}$?

Comment: @BoostMatch Let $k=2^{n-1}$ then $4^{2^{n-1}}-1=4^k-1=(4-1)(4^{k-1}+4^{k-2}+\dots+1)\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Beautiful

Comment: I believe this is true of all powers of 4. I'll double-check in the morning...

Answer (score 3):

We observe that,

$$2^{2^n}+5\equiv 2\left(2^{2^n-1}+1\right)~~\text{(mod 3)}$$

and

$$2^{2^n-1}+1=(2+1)(2^{2^n-2}-2^{2^n-3}+2^{2^n-4}-\cdots+1)$$

This means, $2^{2^n}+5\equiv 0~~\text{(mod 3)}.$

---

But, you can also complete the proof using [mathematical induction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction):

Let $2^n-1=2m-1$, where $m\in\mathbb Z^{+}$.  Then, we can prove the stronger result:

$$2^{2m-1}+1\equiv 0~~\text {(mod 3)},\thinspace \forall m\in\mathbb Z^{+}$$

If $m=1$, then the statement is correct.

Assuming that, the statement is also correct for $m=k~:$

$$2^{2k-1}+1=3n,\thinspace n\in\mathbb Z^{+}$$

Then for $m=k+1$, we have

$$\begin{align}2^{2k+1}+1
&=4(3n-1)+1\\
&=3(4n-1),\thinspace n\in\mathbb Z^{+}\end{align}$$

Then by induction, you are done.

Comment: What is this identity from?

Comment: @BoostMatch This is a well-known formula: $a^n+b^n=(a+b)(a^{n-1}-a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2-...+b^{n-1})$ Here, $n$ is an odd integer.

Answer (score 3):

$2^{2^n}+5 \equiv (-1)^{2^n}-1 \mod 3$.

If $n\ge1$, the exponent is even, and the expression becomes $1-1\equiv 0 \mod 3$.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to prove by induction that $2^m \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ if $m$ is even, because $4 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ (establishing your base case) and $2^{2(k+1)}=4 \cdot 2^{2k} \equiv (\text{using your inductive hypothesis})~1 \cdot 1 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.  (Also, $2^m \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ if $m$ is odd, but you don't need that.)  $2^n$ is always even for $n \geq 1$, so $2^{2^n}+5 \equiv 1+5 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$2^{2^{n+1}}+5=2^{2^n}\cdot (2^{2^n}+5)- (5\cdot (2^{2^n}-1))$$

Why this helps, is that $$2^{2^n}-1\equiv 2^{2^n}+5\pmod 3$$ so if either is a multiple of $3$ both are.  This means we'd have a difference of multiples of $3$ , which is then a multiple of $3$. So we have the induction hypothesis proved. We now need a base case. $n=1$ produces $$2^{2^1}+5=2^2+5=4+5=9$$ which is an obvious multiple of $3$, so we are done.